# Call class as array, only if input is array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have been in the process of creating an algo, but I've ran into a problem that has stopped me in my tracks. The problem stems from the following API response:

```
{
    "topic": "trade.BTCUSDT",
    "data": [
        {
            "symbol": "BTCUSDT",
            "tick_direction": "PlusTick",
            "price": 8098,
            "size": 328,
            "timestamp":"2020-03-30T02:21:06.000Z",
            "trade_time_ms":"1585534866418",
            "side":"Sell",
            "trade_id":"01e79e28-d1f4-59ac-b079-ca909606d91a"
        }
    ]
}
```

This didn't initially pose any problems, as I called data as an array when deserialising with the Newtonsoft.Json package, and took the first variable to alleviate the problem. I am in the process of combining all responses, and sorting them based on their response topic. This response is the only response that holds data with square brackets rather than curly brackets. To fix, this, I attempted to edit the get; set; command as follows, but came out with a stack overflow.

```
public Data[] data { get { if (_data != null) { return new[] { _data }; } else { return data; } } set { if (value.Length == 1) { _data = value[0]; } else { data = value; } } }
```

My question is, is it possible to set my `get; set;` to class the Data class as an array if only one element has been set?

Comment: Can you show another kind of json you can get, pls? It is hard to understand what is the difference. What do you want to get in each case?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of determining if it an array or not - why not just create your classes like this, and it will serialize automatically:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string tick_direction { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public string trade_time_ms { get; set; }
    public string side { get; set; }
    public string trade_id { get; set; }
}

public class Trade
{
    public string topic { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that other deserializations use a single version of data, so the whole program gets stopped.

Comment: You can't have a property that can be an array or a single instance. You will require two properties or two classes.